# Would it work to use 2 wireless mouse receivers on 2 diffrent PCs and have them simultaneously working on both computers

Tags: desktop-computer, wireless-mouse

Im not trying to have a dual monitor setup and i dont want to darg it between them. I need them both to work at the same time and duplicate the cursor. A program like synergy only makes it work on one at a time so thats not what i need. I need a way to have my mouse click on the two PCs at the same time. I cant find any way of doing it so im putting the question out here and see if anyone knows or has a diffrent solution.

Answer (score 0):

It *can* work.  I have done this with [Logitech Unifying receivers](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/unifying-receiver-usb) and devices in the past.  I was able to pair one device to multiple receivers.  I do not know if it sill works, but I dont see why it wouldnt.

However, this might not work as well for a mouse.  Lag, missed packets of transmission, whatever can cause the two pointers to come out of alignment.  Other things to consider would be the screen resolutions would need to match.  The mouse settings would need to be identical, like acceleration and precision.  Probably other settings as well.

There is no harm in trying it.  I just have my doubts as to how well it would work.

There are macro recording programs for mouse and keyboards.  However, they record actions and then let you replay them.  As for any other options, none that I can think of.